# Problems implement Toolbar with TabLayout ..

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

The code is given below .What i want is the Toolbar should scroll away with the content but the TabLayout should stick to the top ..

I am not able to find out the error . Logcat error is at the end !!...

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="alphasniper.com.github.collapsibletoolbartablayout.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dummy_text"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.java code....

```
    package alphasniper.com.github.collapsibletoolbartablayout;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 4"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 5"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 6"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 7"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 8"));

    }
}
```

Logacat Error :::

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/TintManager;
```

Thanks in advance !!..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this in gradle(as of today latest version is 23.1.1, so it may change in future versions)

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

you can keep your tools version (23.1.1)

let me now if it not worked for you.

Comment: I have gradle file configured to compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.+' already !!.. but just not able to find the problem